# Multiple transactions selecting same foreign key rows results in lock wait timeout

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

I have some heavy data importing features in application written in sylius (symfony ecommerce).

We have bunch of csv files which we use to sync data. The whole workflow is implemented with **rabbitmq** and **supervisor processes**. We have multiple processes for each consumer. The workflow I presented in image bellow.

[image]

When the action for inserting into first table is completed, event is fired and actions in second row are triggered.

This is where process comes to issue. All of these actions in second row select foreign keys which are in table that is inserted into first action, so I get into **lock wait timeout error**.

Message gets queued back, but the process seems to halt over and over again.

Is there something I can do in this situation, with concurent transactions?

Queries are in form like this, more or less with slight modifications on use case basis:

```
INSERT INTO product_variant(productid, other_attribute)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM product WHERE ...), 'value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insertion process is something like this.

```
 INSERT INTO products (this, that, something, else)
               VALUES (?,?,?,?);
 SELECT id FROM products WHERE this=? AND that=?;
 INSERT INTO product_variants ( product_id, col,...) 
                      VALUES   (<<that id you just SELECTED>>, ...);
```

In other words, you have a sequence of INSERTs followed by SELECTs.  That's an industrial recipe for deadlocks on a busy DBMS.

Try to avoid the SELECTs by using [MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).   It gives you back the autoincrementing ID value, usually the primary key, after any insert.  Do something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO products (this, that, something, else)
               VALUES (?,?,?,?);
 SET @product_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO product_variants ( product_id, col,...) 
                      VALUES   (@product_id, ...);
 SET @product_variant_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then you won't need to intersperse INSERTs with SELECTs just to get the id value. The SET operations in my example allow you to re-use the id value for an INSERT operation; The next INSERT overwrites the LAST_INSERT_ID value, so you need to retain the value if it's used as a foreign key in subsequent INSERTs.

Also, try wrapping your sequences of INSERTs in `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;`.

Also, try reducing the number of processes consuming data from your queue. Paradoxically, too many concurrent operations on a DBMS can reduce performance. And concurrency definitely increases the chance of deadlocks.

**Edit** Of course all your related inserts must be done in a single DBMS connection for LAST_INSERT_ID to be useful.

Another possible approach to retrieve the right value for a foreign key and then use it for an insert.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT id INTO @fk
  FROM master_table
 WHERE whatever
   AND whatever
   FOR UPDATE;
 INSERT INTO detail_table (master_id, col, col, col)
                   VALUES (@fk, ?, ?);
 COMMIT;
```

This SELECT ... FOR UPDATE puts a transaction lock on the row of the master table you're working with. If you follow this pattern carefully, it should result in each operation taking the locks it needs in the same order. Which is the industrial recipe for preventing deadlocks.  If you need to get FK values from multiple tables to do an operation, always mention the tables in the same order in your SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statements

But still, LAST_INSERT_ID is by far the best-performing and most reliable way of doing this work. You should consider refactoring your code to use it wherever possible.

Comment: At the current code base, after whole processing of file is done in one action, then event is triggered and other actions are then processing the same file. So at current state I can't use LAST_INSERT_ID because those actions are ran in separate transactions and operations. I will try to reduce number of processes. I read something about different mysql lock types, such as `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` would that help me in any ways?